# Confusion in understanding tuple and *args in Python

Tags: python, tuples, args

I need a function which would be taking `variadic arguments`. The number of arguments may vary from 1 to N.

```
def abc(*args):
    print "ABC"
    print args
    print len(args)

def abc1(*args):
    print "ABC1"
    print args
    print len(args)
    print "------------"


tup = ("Hello123")
abc(*tup)
abc1(tup)
tup = ("Hello123", "Hello1234")
abc(*tup)
abc1(tup)
```

The ouput of the above program is;

```
ABC
('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '1', '2', '3')
8
ABC1
('Hello123',)
1
------------
ABC
('Hello123', 'Hello1234')
2
ABC1
(('Hello123', 'Hello1234'),)
1
------------
```

If I look into this output,when i am passing only 1 argument in `abc1()`, the length of tuple becomes `8`(keeping `*tup`), where as in the `abc1()` it shows the length is `1`. `why and how?`
But the same is not working differently when I am passing 2 arguments in the code above. The output comes as `tuple` and `tuple of tuple`.
How to resolve this problem because I have to write the code which will work for all N

Comment: `tup = ("Hello123")` does not create a tuple.  This is just the string "Hello123" with parentheses around it.  If you want a tuple with one element, you have to put a trailing comma, like so: `tup = ("Hello123",)`.  This syntax can look a bit odd, but it's needed so that expressions like `x = (y / 2)` are not interpreted as tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Parentheses* don't make tuples, *commas* do. To build a single-element tuple, the correct syntax is

```
tup = ("Hello123",)  # parentheses are optional but help readability
```

which is equivalent to

```
tup = "Hello123",
```

Remember that you can write

```
x, y = y, x  # swaps x and y using tuple packing/unpacking
```

just as well as

```
(x, y) = (y, x)
```

The only exception where parentheses are *mandatory* is the empty tuple `()`.

Comment: To add to your last sentence, you also need parentheses if the commas would otherwise mean something else. For instance, function arguments and list items are both separated by commas, so to build a tuple in those environments, you need parentheses (e.g. `foo((x,y))` and `[(x,y)]`).